# Custom renovate presets on Butbucket-server

Tags: bitbucket-server, renovate

I just tried to create a custom preset for renovate as described [here](https://docs.renovatebot.com/config-preset). My goal was to ban certain versions of dependencies. So I created a JSON file `my.json` like this:

```json
{
    "packageRules": [
        {
            "matchPackageNames": ["commons-logging"],
            "allowedVersions": "!/.*-does-not-exist$/"
        }
    ]
}
```

As we are using bitbucket-server, I've put it into a repository called `renovate-config` in a project lets say `XYZ`. I changed the `renovate.json` file on the master branch of one service to:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
    "extends": [
        "config:base",
        "local>XYZ/renovate-config//my"
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately renovate is not picking this up. The provider is configured correctly and renovate is fully working with our bitbucket-server instance, but it is either not picking up the preset, or anything else is going amiss.

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Here is the solution:
Actually my approach was correct. And the preset was retrieved and applied. I just made a mistake in formulating the rules:

This works:

```json
{
    "packageRules": [
        {
            "matchPackageNames": [".*:commons-logging"],
            "allowedVersions": "!/.*-does-not-exist$/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Mind the `.*:` added at the beginning of the package name. For Maven artifacts this needs to include the groupId.

I also found that when activating debug or trace logging it is pretty clear what happens.